# Google Play Android: issue while publishing a new build as staged rollout

Tags: android, google-play

I have an existing build with 100% rollout.
But, when I am rolling out new android build with 5% rollout I am getting following error :

Fully shadowed APK
PROBLEM
This APK will not be served to any users because it is completely shadowed by one or more APKs with higher version codes.
RESOLUTION
Remove this APK from your release or review the targeting and version codes of the APKs that you are including in this release.

Any idea how to solve this issue and have 2 builds, 1 with 5% rollout and other with 95% rollout.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48i17.png)